# C# WPF "private" Anonymous Type member

Tags: c#, wpf

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(SomeRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        Type_member1 = "StacOverFlow",
        Type_member2 = sometext,
        Type_member3 = 0,
        private = true
    });
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}
```

As you can see, there is Type member called "private". Of course, when i typed it, a message will pop-up and tell me:

> "Invalid expression term 'private'"

Putting "private" inside quote will return this error:

> "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. bla bla bla..."

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: why don't you change it to be `Private` then since C# is case sensitive

Comment: @MethodMan thx for your advice but i think user2864740's answer is the best solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private` is a reserved keyword of C# framework and can not it used as identifier in program. If you try to write `string private = "sometext";` then compiler will throw exception by own stating `Identifier 'private' is a keyword`. 
So you should define the prop name as @private

Or you should inform serialize to name it as private at time of serialization.

Answer (score 6):

This can be solved by using the syntax:

```
@private = true,
```

Note the use of `@private` ([where the @ changes how the compiler interprets the source code)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396); and changing the `;` to a `,` to avoid the other syntax error.

> Keywords [ie. `private`] are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, `@if` [ie. `@private`] is a valid identifier but `if` [ie. `private`] is not because if is a keyword.

Alternative, create a non-anonymous type (with a better code-friendly member name) and apply a `[JsonProperty]` or `[DataMember]` attribute to change the serialized name to 'private'.

Comment: Since this your answer is identical with the one above, so i choose his answer because he answered first. Sorry :)  btw thx for the answer!